# Timers behave differently with the same settings

Tags: c, stm32

I am using STM32F401RCT6 chip, and I am trying to do some controlled PWM outputs. I am using TIM1, 2, 3, and 11 for PWM.

The thing is, when I set the same period for timer 1 as for any other timer, the period is the same length but the pulse is different. For example, TIM1 is pulse 6.9us and for others 82.4us when using period 4999.

[The picture shows that the period is the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymFMv.jpg)

[The next picture shows the difference in the pulse length.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuXZh.jpg)

When I change the pulse from 10 to 1000 the pulse for TIM1 is 720us and for TIM2 794us.

When I saw the difference, the first thing which comes to my mind was that the timers have a different frequency, but the thing is that it would have different frequency of PWM pulse too, but it is not the case.

Can anyone say, what can cause the pulse length to be shorter for timer 1?

My settings are the following:

```
void MX_TIM11_Init(void)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  htim11.Instance = TIM11;
  htim11.Init.Prescaler = HAL_RCC_GetPCLK2Freq()/124999;
  htim11.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim11.Init.Period = 0;
  htim11.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim11.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim11) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim11) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC1REF;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim11, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim11);
}

void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = HAL_RCC_GetPCLK1Freq()/124999;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 0;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC1REF;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);
}

void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = HAL_RCC_GetPCLK1Freq()/124999;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 0;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC1REF;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);
}

void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = HAL_RCC_GetPCLK2Freq()/124999;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 0;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC1REF;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);
}
```

I have following function to set parameters for PWM and for starting it:

```
void setPWM(TIM_HandleTypeDef timer, uint32_t channel, uint16_t period)
{
    // stop generation of PWM
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&timer, channel);
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;
    // set the period duration
    timer.Init.Period = period;
    // re-initialize with new period value
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&timer);
    sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    // set the pulse duration
    sConfigOC.Pulse = 10;
    sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&timer, &sConfigOC, channel);
    // start PWM generation
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&timer, channel);
}
```

UPDATE:
I need to change the period during the run, and it seems like if I call the setPWM function more then once, the problem occurs. The first call appears to be behaving as it should. The weird thing is that I call it the same way for all of the timers but only one will lose the length of the pulse. But right now I have run out of ideas about what to try to find the core of my problem.

Any Idea what I can try to find what cause it?

Thank you,
Hana

Comment: You are using a different clock source for timer 1 and the other timers (`PCLK2` and `PCLK2`, respectively).  Perhaps the frequencies of `PCLK1` and `PCLK2` are different.

Comment: That's the first thing that came to my mind, but the problem is, that it would cause the frequency of PWM to be different too, not only the pulse. And I am using the clock source for timer 11 too, and it has the same length of the pulse as others, the only difference is the timer 1.

Comment: HAL makes everything complex.

Comment: I don't know this particular STM32  but I think there is a register `TIMx_CCR` that configures the duty cycle of the PWM. Did you check that ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure if I understand it right. The period is set in ARR register. There is the pulse length, which is in CCR1 register. From this two, the duty can be calculated. It is set by:
'''
timer.Init.Period = period;
'''
and
'''
sConfigOC.Pulse = 10;
'''
In the setPWM. What exactly should I check?

Comment: You need to check the actual register values using a debugger to see if ARR and CCR registers have the values you expect.

Comment: Yes, they are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now all timers are working the same way. I am not sure why it was reacting differently on timer 1, but if I do not call setPWM() again and instead I just set the ARR register while running, it behaves the same for all timers.

```
timer.Instance->ARR = period;
```

Comment: exactly what I wrote. setting the register works. magic HAL does not